# Проблемы с Python 3 pip

Tags: python, pip

При любом контакте с pip получаю такую ошибку в командной строке. Последняя версия Python 3.6.0

Путь в окружении указывал в ручную отдельно "C:\Users\Vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Scripts"

И отдельно "C:\Users\Vlad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пробовали на 3.5 версии проверять (у меня на ней проблем не обнаружилось)

Comment: Да, в 5,2 все работает отлично

Comment: в какой-какой версии питона? :)

Comment: Мои извинения 3.5.2

Comment: поставил 3.6 норм. pip --version покажите

Comment: Вы случайно свой tokenize.py не создали?

Comment: Верся pip та что в камплекте. Нет,  tokenize не создовал

Comment: возможно у вас ошибка с установлением pip или де он не добавлен в переменную windows